# Random Forests heuristic guideline for the ratio of max_leaf_nodes to sample size

Tags: time-series, classification, random-forest, scikit-learn, hyperparameter

In Random Forests, is there a reference or heuristic guideline for the ratio of max_leaf_nodes to n (sample size)?

Assume a small time series binary classification problem modeled using random forests, and python scikit learn. The data is very wide, i.e. a large number of variables compared to the sample size. It is hard to get reliable cross validation results due to the small sample size, and because model performance depends on factors that are not limited to CV SSE or similar. I would therefore like to manually limit the capacity of the algorithm.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.02587v1 I found this paper today which seems to agree with the premise of the question: growing shallower trees can improve the performance of the model.

Comment: One more tip: growing more trees can reduce the variance of the model. However, it sounds like the main reason that you're having volatility in CV estimates is just that you have a small sample size -- means of small sample sizes have a wide sampling variance by their nature.